# How to filter GraphQL query by content language?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am coding Drupal 8/Angular app and Angular is fetching data from Drupal using GraphQL. Everything works fine except now I need to query nodes in a particular language. This is my query:

````
{
  nodeQuery(filter:
    {conditions: [
      {field: "type", value: "akcia", operator: EQUAL, language: EN},
      {field: "field_datum", value: "2018-02-12T18:00:00", operator: GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL}
      {field: "langcode", value: "en", operator: EQUAL}
    ]}
    sort: {field: "field_datum", direction: DESC}
  )
  {
    entities {
      entityLanguage {
        id
      }
      ... on NodeAkcia {
        nid
        langcode {
          value
        }
        title
        fieldDatum {
          value
        }
        body {
          value
        }
        fieldObrazok {
          url
        }
        path {
          alias
          pid
          langcode
          pathauto
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```

Notice the `{field: "langcode", value: "en", operator: EQUAL}` line - that's the best thing I came up with, however, the query returns Slovak version of that node, not the English one.

Is there any better way ho to filter nodes based on their translation?
````

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct but you need to retrieve the entityTranslation in your entities, something like below for an article in English for example:

```
 entities {
    ...on NodeArticle {
      entityTranslation(language: EN) {
        entityLabel
      }
    }
  }
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551190/how-to-get-a-specific-translation-of-drupal-node-with-graphql/56759444#56759444) for a similar question and answer.